# Работа в Pycharm на пк с proxy

Tags: python, pycharm, proxy, модули

Python 3.9.5
pip 21.1.1
Комп в домене организации, использует проксю для инета. При импорте любого модуля в пайчарме ошибка:

```
    ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
   File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
```

ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В найтройках пайчарма пробовал выставлять как и рекомендуют авто проксю, и манюал ставил, ничего не помогает, ошибка одна и та же. Какие еще варианты? Выключить проксю тоже не помогло.

Comment: единственное что смущает это то, что вы настраиваете сам ПЧ, от такой-же ошибки с либой `requests` помогло `pip install requests[socks] --upgrade`

Comment: обновить тоже не дает(   raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

Comment: Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\ххх\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так:
установил HTTP в PyCharm  hostname port login password.

потом набираем команду

```
pip install --proxy=http://xxxxxx.xx:port модуль
```

сработало на ура.

Answer (score 0):

сработала версия - `pip install pandas --proxy http://login:pass@proxy.dot.ru:8888`